# Infinite FragmentStatePagerAdapter with different fragment classes

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, infinite-scroll, fragmentstatepageradapter

I came across a strange issue in my project.

I have implemented infinite viewpager adapter using FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Code for same is:

```
public class DashBoardAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    ArrayList<AbstractFragment> fragments;

    private int MAXFRAGMENTS=0;

    public DashBoardAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<AbstractFragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
        MAXFRAGMENTS=fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public AbstractFragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position%MAXFRAGMENTS);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position%MAXFRAGMENTS).getTitle();
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        int virtualPosition = position % MAXFRAGMENTS;
        return super.instantiateItem(container, virtualPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        int virtualPosition = position % MAXFRAGMENTS;
        super.destroyItem(container, virtualPosition, object);
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
        MAXFRAGMENTS = fragments.size();
    }
}
```

And the Main `Activity`code(Function only) is something like this:

```
public void initializeViewPager()
    {

        verticalViewPager = (VerticalViewPager) findViewById(R.id.verticalviewpager);
        enabledPages=new ArrayList<>();
        enabledPages.addAll(getEnabledPages(false));
        adapter=new DashBoardAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),enabledPages);
        verticalViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        verticalViewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new PageTransformer());
        verticalViewPager.setCurrentItem(999+position);
        verticalViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);

        verticalViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                if(adapter!=null)
                    title.setText(adapter.getPageTitle(position));
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
    }

    private ArrayList<AbstractFragment> getEnabledPages(boolean a)
    {
        ArrayList<AbstractFragment> fragments=new ArrayList<>();
        fragments.add(FragmentAttendance.newInstance(fragments.size()));
        fragments.add(FragmentCompensation.newInstance(fragments.size()));
        if(a)
            fragments.add(FragmentTimeOff.newInstance(fragments.size()));
        if(a)
         fragments.add(FragmentCalendar.newInstance(fragments.size()));
        if(a)
            fragments.add(FragmentPeople.newInstance(fragments.size()));
        if(a)
            fragments.add(FragmentProvisions.newInstance(fragments.size()));

        position = fragments.size()-(999+position)%fragments.size();

        return fragments;
    }
```

Layout of activity contains just a `Viewpager`.

And the Fragments, I have used is just copy of below fragment with different names

```
public class FragmentAttendance extends AbstractFragment {
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    String title ="Testing";
    public static FragmentAttendance newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        FragmentAttendance fragment = new FragmentAttendance();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public FragmentAttendance() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_attendance, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

Layout of fragment has just `LinearLayout` with a `TextView`.

The code is running superb if I am adding fragments more than three fragments. Howsoever as soon as the number of added fragments gets below four. My code Works in strange behavior.

Some of errors are `Fragment already initialised`
Other are Forward scrolling shows fragement View Howsoever when I scroll `backward No view appears`.

The working code can be tested by passing true to getEnabledPages(true);
And the non working code can be tested by passing false to getEnabledPages(false);

Please someone help me in this strange behaviour.